# Bluetooth Logitech mouse not recognized by Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I updated Ubuntu 18 to 20 and can now not connect to the internet. After trying various fixes I reinstalled Ubuntu 16 from an old USB thumb drive. I can now connect to the internet but Ubuntu 16 does not recognize my wireless Logitech mouse. It does recognize a plugged in wired mouse, so I think the problem is with bluetooth device recognition.  I installed Solaar, which is the Linux device manger for Logitec via Synaptic but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Also if you have any ideas on how to fix the internet issue with Ubuntu 20, please let me know. I read online that it was a bug and that's way beyond my computer skills to fix. Thank you

Comment: I suggest installing Ubuntu 20.04 and asking a question regarding the "internet" issue. Now the question is not answerable.

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *yy* format are not intended for desktop or server use, they are specialist releases for appliances & cloud based VMs. Try a regularl Ubuntu *yy.mm* release esp. desktop such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop as already suggested.  Ubuntu *yy* releases are intended for use in *headless* devices, and whilst desktops can be added, as they're running inside *snap* environments they aren't the same.

Comment: You've tagged 16.04, but that's a different product to Ubuntu Core 16 (your question only mentions *yy* based releases)